# Center logo with navbar and cart option wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, navbar

How can i design Center logo with nav menu In Wordpress.In Mobile view i need Search icon and Cart icon.and Static navbar needed. Some examples https://biona.co.uk/ http://palkova.in I tried different themes but now work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this kind of nav style is not available in theme. You have use lots of themes to search for this type of navigation style or you have to build custom navigation.

Comment: Can you suggest some type of themes? Also needed Woo commerce supported

Comment: In the OceanWp theme there is an option to add logo in the center, also woo support. You can try it.